# last line of a csv file

Tags: php, csv

Good evening, I’d like a little help from you with a CSV file.

My code is this.

```
<?php

$line = '';
$f = fopen('C:\Users\User\Documents\OMRON FZ\USBDisk\Conteggio.csv', 'r');
$cursor = -1;
fseek($f, $cursor, SEEK_END);
$char = fgetc($f);
//Trim trailing newline characters in the file
while ($char === "\n" || $char === "\r") {
   fseek($f, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
   $char = fgetc($f);
}
//Read until the next line of the file begins or the first newline char
while ($char !== false && $char !== "\n" && $char !== "\r") {
   //Prepend the new character
   $line = $char . $line;
   fseek($f, $cursor--, SEEK_END);
   $char = fgetc($f);
}
echo $line;

?>
```

CSV data are saved on a single line. For example: ROWS1, RESULT1,RESULT2,RESULT3,

Can I decide to show myself the only result saved on the same line, for example, the print of RESULT3 only?

[final result that I would like to obtain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs1Zs.png)

Comment: Please share more details - what do you want to achieve? What **exactly** is not working with the given code?

Comment: @antonio You can show yourself whatever you want: it's your file. I don't understand your question.

Comment: I have attached the image

Comment: @AntonioValentin I edited my answer to fit your need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `file()` to read the file into an array of lines. The last line will be the last element of the array. Then you can use `str_getcsv()` to parse this into fields and get the last field.

```
$lines = file('C:\Users\User\Documents\OMRON FZ\USBDisk\Conteggio.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
if (!empty($lines)) {
    $fields = str_getcsv($lines[count($lines)-1]); // get fields from last line
    echo $fields[count($fields)-1]; // print last field
} else {
    echo "CSV is empty";
}
```

Comment: ok thanks for your answer, now for each result I add a string, but how can I print only the greater result?
since every second changes result in the csv file.

Comment: There's nothing in the question about printing the greatest result, it just says you want the last result. Are you talking about real-time updates when new lines are added to the file, like `tail -f`? I'm not sure how easy that is to do in PHP.